# Powershell extract multiple occurrences in multi-lines

Tags: regex, string, powershell, pem

I have a text file that has thousands of binary certificates, this is a sample of it.

```
Row 1:
  Binary Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFtzCCBJ+gAwIBAgIKGUNYAwAAAAAAODANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Row 2:
  Binary Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGEzCCBPugAwIBAgIKGVe6uwAAAAAAOTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Row 3:
  Binary Certificate:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGMzCCBRugAwIBAgIKGYrkyAAAAAAAOjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE
```

I need to output each certificate to a separate file. What I'm struggling with is how to extract from "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" all the way to the first "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" to save it to a variable/file, then go and find the next match and so on.

The output of each match should look like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFtzCCBJ+gAwIBAgIKGUNYAwAAAAAAODANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have tried multiple Regex's with no luck :[

Is there a way, whether Regex or String.Split that can do this match/split?

Comment: Are they all the same length like that?  5 lines a piece with the Row/Binary header?

Comment: How do you want to name the single files? Row number? Incrementing number?

Answer (score 2):

If the contents are exactly like you stated above then this should work on extracting the Key.

```
$File = "C:\Test.txt"
$content = Get-Content $file
$contents =  $content

$Complete = [regex]::split($contents, "BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----(.*?)-----END CERTIFICATE")

for($i = 1; $i -lt $Complete.Length; $i =$i+2){
    $Complete[$i] -replace " ","`r`n"
}
```

Comment: > `$i = 1`  I feel like a sin has been committed.

Answer (score 2):

This script will read file `sample.pem` and save each found certificate incrementing the number to `cert#.pem`

```
## Q:\Test\2017\08\25\SO_45884754.ps1

$Pattern = '(?smi)^-{2,}BEGIN CERTIFICATE-{2,}.*?-{2,}END CERTIFICATE-{2,}'
Get-Content .\sample.PEM -raw | 
    Select-String  -Pattern $Pattern -Allmatches| 
      ForEach-Object {$Cnt=0;$_.Matches}| ForEach-Object {
          $Cnt++
          Set-Content -Value $_.Value -Path ("Cert{0}.pem" -f $Cnt)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be several ways to this. PowerShell 5 has a new feature that can be used to detect patterns, for example. Anything is possible with regex, though it is always a bit cryptic. If you wanted to do good ol' easy to read/understand script, you could do something like this:

```
$begin_certificate='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE'
$end_certificate  ='-----END CERTIFICATE'

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$certs=@()

$add_next = $false

$all_certs = get-content C:\Temp\a.txt 

Foreach ($line in $all_certs) {


    if ( $line.StartsWith($begin_certificate)) {
        $add_next = $true
        $cert_content = $begin_certificate
        continue
    }

    if ($add_next) {     
        $cert_content += "`n$line"             

        if ($line.StartsWith($end_certificate)) {
            $add_next = $false            
            [void]$certs.add($cert_content) # don't print the result of operation           
        }
    }
}
# This array list has all the certs now
$certs
```

With the file sample you have given above, you would get 3 items in certs and following as output:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE
MIIFtzCCBJ+gAwIBAgIKGUNYAwAAAAAAODANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE
MIIGEzCCBPugAwIBAgIKGVe6uwAAAAAAOTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE
MIIGMzCCBRugAwIBAgIKGYrkyAAAAAAAOjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBxMQswCQYD
VQQGEwJERTEcMBoGA1UECBMTTm9yZHJoZWluLVdlc3RmYWxlbjENMAsGA1UEBxME
Qm9ubjEWMBQGA1UEChMNRGV1dHNjaGUgUG9zdDEdMBsGA1UEAxMURFBESEwgVExT
-----END CERTIFICATE
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed... works perfectly!! :)